# how to use one size of image in android

Tags: android, image

I am using more than 400 images in my android application each of different sizes placed in

respective drawable folders(ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi).
This makes my app heavy.
Is there any way to use only one image size for all the android devices of different screen

densities?
I have used 9-patch images but it looks very blurred especiallyin ldpi devices.
I have tried to use SVG but getting error- java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException.
I dont know whether I am going wrong with adding SVG jar file in my android application.
Please provide me the steps for adding SVG jar file in my android application.
Please let me know if there is any solution other than 9-patch and SVG that I can use for

making android application.

Comment: You can only use the xhdpi folder and Android wil scale the images accordingly.

Comment: I have tried. Not working!! :(

Comment: What's the min, target versions of the API in your `AndroidManifest`?

Comment: android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="17"

Comment: Android can re-scale the images, but it takes as baseline the mdpi folder. This can however produce images with poor quality. Is this really necessary, I mean, you risk some degradation in the image quality?

Comment: Also take a look at this thread: http://jayxie.com/mirrors/android-sdk/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 2):

You can make a single drawable folder and store all your images in the one folder.

res/drawable

Answer (score 0):

store all your xxhdpi images in xxhdpi drawable and no need to store mdpi,ldpi,hdpi images in respective drawable folders.